# Image not covering container on smaller resolutions

Tags: css, wordpress

I tried solving the problem myself, but I can't do it.

Go to my site here:

http://digesale.com/

And scroll down to the footer. Just above the footer you will see an image. It's the one that says "Get Things Done, Start Buying," etc. That's the image I have a problem with...

On my browser/resolution it looks perfectly aligned, but a friend told me that on his resolution it doesn't cover the entire space left-to-right. If you press "Ctrl+-" on your keyboard you'll see the problem.

This is the code I use to put that image there:

```
<img style="margin-bottom: -20px;" src="http://digesale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/digesale-buy-how-it-works.png" alt="Digesale - How it works!" height="300" width="1350">
```

Can anyone help me make that image cover the whole width of that section so that it looks good even on smaller screen resolutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to cover you can use the image as a background:

```
 <div class="background"></div>
```

and in the css

```
 .background {
     background: url(http://digesale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/digesale-buy-how-it-works.png) top left no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

The important part is `background-size: cover` because it fill the entire div in all cases.

## EDIT

If you want another behaviour, you can use your old img tag

```
 <img src="http://digesale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/digesale-buy-how-it-works.png" alt="Digesale - How it works!" class="responsive-img">
```

And the css

```
 .responsive-img { 
     margin-bottom: -20px; /* this was writting in inline style. */
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Well, when I do that nothing shows. Look at the site now, there's no image there or nothing...

Comment: Sure? Where can I see? What div you are applying it?

Comment: Well, I replaced my code with <div class="background"></div> and then put the CSS in stylesheet. If you inspect element it falls under id="stretch-footer-area."

Comment: Well, you have your div with 0px height. You need to specify the parent height, or change `.background` height to `.background { height: 350px }` and you can see how background is responsive.

Comment: Right. So I changed the height to 350px. And now the image looks good for me, but once I change it to a smaller resolution, basically a fourth of the image gets hidden/not-visible anymore.

Comment: Yes, it covers in width and height for avoid white zones in the div. If this solution is not as you like, you can make it with your old `<img>` tag. I put another answer to this

Comment: Okay. I'll make it as it was before.

Comment: Done. I made it as it was before with the <img> tag.

Comment: That did it Marcos Perez Gude. I did change the height to 300px to make the image a bit smaller. I guess I should alter the image itself, but it's good as it is now. It works for smaller resolutions and everything is fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is better if you don't scale without proportions the image. The height:auto is for this purpose. If your image is so large, maybe you need to modify the image per se.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I know. That's what I meant, I should modify the image itself. That would be best. But it's okay the way it is now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below CSS

```
.background {
  background: url(http://digesale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/digesale-buy-how-it-works.png) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26vw;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I already got the solution above from Marcos.

Comment: Wow. I just tried your "26vw" that you put for height, amazing. I am using that instead of px for my need here. Great stuff. I never knew that existed. It doesn't minimize the image as bad on smaller resolutions, so it ends up looking better. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.